# Wordpress theme fails to load, /js/jquery.php?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-hosting

```
Warning: require_once(/js/jquery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/jamie/public_html/drexelreviews.com/wp-content/themes/instant/functions.php on line 494

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/js/jquery.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home1/jamie/public_html/drexelreviews.com/wp-content/themes/instant/functions.php on line 494
```

I open jquery.php and the file is blank,

Im not sure where this is coming from /opt/php54/lib/php
Im running wordpress 3.8.1 in hostgator... any suggestions?

Comment: Tried $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you include the  file  try to give the full path

```
<?php  bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.php
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is your dynamic js file you still need to enqueue it.. the code in functions.php can be something like this...

```
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
  'custom-script',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.php',
  array( 'jquery' )
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Io you are in a WordPress template file..
Try to call  `get_template_part('js/jquery');`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using something like this to require the file

```
<?php require_once ('/js/jquery.php');?>
```

Wordpress will require the file from the root. so in this case there is no such file.

If you are requiring on a file inside your themes folder "e.g. foobar-theme" you need to require as

`<?php require_once (get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.php');?`>

Finall Note check if you have set the correct Mime type on top of your jquery.php (assuming your requirment is to run js code)

> Content-Type: application/javascript